# Pgf - fpu library problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

Maybe a well known problem, how to avoid the trailing useless `0` for an integer ?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1,...,3} {\m\ }

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1,...,3} {\m\ }
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\pgfmathprintnumber{\m}`, but that is perhaps not what you were after?

Comment: Exactly that. Could you write an answer please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could feed `\m` into `\pgfmathprintnumber`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepgflibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1,...,3} {\m\ }

\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using int(\n+1)] in {1,...,3} {\pgfmathprintnumber{\m}\ }
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simpler syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,xfp}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\xforeach}{mO{1}mm}
 {
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xforeach{1}{3}{#1 }

\xforeach{1}{3}{\inteval{#1+1} }

\xforeach{1}{3}{\fpeval{round(sqrt(#1),4)} }

\end{document}
```

[image]

The optional argument is the step, you can try `\xforeach{1}[2]{5}{#1 }`. You can also pass `\fpeval` to `\num` of `siunitx`. For instance,

```
\xforeach{1}[3]{7}{\fpeval{round(pi^(#1),3)} }
```

will produce

[image]